# Can Picasso Android load XML URL link images?

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, picasso

I have a question in mind while I'm developing an Android app. So basically I have a AutoCompleteTextView and I'm currently loading a list of country codes alongside it's respective image URL.

Here's how my Image URL looks like --> "http://localhost:30776/icons/svg/afghanistan_adobe_express.xml". [Note that I replace "localhost" with my computer's IP address since I'm hosting the REST API on my local Kubernetes]

Here's the code I've typed to load the image into my ImageView using Picasso:
`Picasso.get().load(countryCode.countryIcon). placeholder(R.drawable.niger_adobe_express).into(countryCodeFlagImageView)`

So now, "countryCode.countryIcon" will have the link as mentioned above with the "XML" extension but will Picasso load it, it seems it doesn't load at my end even though I've accessed the link via the mobile browser.

Please help if anyone has any solution to this issue. Thanks!

Comment: You should start realizing if an ImageView can display an .xml file. Test with loading same xml file from device storage.  Please tell us. Only when possible you can talk about Picasso or other libraries.

Comment: Maybe i'm talking nonsense as Picasso could make a bitmap from the xml and then feed the ImageView with it. Could be the scenario even if an ImageView could not display an xml file.

Comment: @blackapps if an ImageView is able to load drawables which are most probably XML file, then why doesn't Picasso load it into the target of an ImageView?

Comment: Ok. Dont know. Never used Picasso.

Comment: `"http://` Http? No https? Did you enable clear text traffic in application tag in manifest file?

Comment: @blackapps yes I did mentioned it in my application tag, still not working though